# FME - Use Python Caller to Set Search Envelope in Another Workspace

Tags: python, fme-form, parameters, transformer

I have an FME workspace which has a number of different workspaceRunner transformers.  The first workspaceRunner launches a workspace which buffers a pipeline and outputs the bounding coordinates to a CSV file.

I then have a python caller which reads the CSV to get the bounding coordinates and save them as global variables.

[image]

The code of the Python Script looks like this:

```
import fmeobjects
import csv

# Template Function interface:
def processFeature(feature):
    global XMIN
    global XMAX
    global YMIN
    global YMAX


    outputDirectory = FME_MacroValues['Output_Directory']
    csvPath = outputDirectory + '\\Buffer Bounds.csv'
    coordlist = []

    with open(csvPath, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for row in reader:
            coordlist.append(row)

    XMIN = float(coordlist[0][0])
    XMAX = float(coordlist[0][2])
    YMIN = float(coordlist[0][3])
    YMAX = float(coordlist[0][4])    

    print XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX
    pass

# Template Class Interface:
class FeatureProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def input(self,feature):
        self.pyoutput(feature)
    def close(self):
        pass
```

After the PythonCaller, I have four VariableRetriever transformers which get the values of XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX and save them as attributes.

That is then connected to a workspaceRunner transformer.  The parameters for the bounding box are passed to the next workspace and are used to define the Search Envelope Coordinates for the File Geodatabase.

[image]

[image]

My problem is that these variables are somehow not getting passed to the attributes.  Am I using the variableRetriever transformers correctly?  I have read on some FME forums that you can use them this way.  I've declared them as global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I didn't need to use a VariableRetriever or VariableSetter transformer.  I first create the attributes that will hold the bounds:

[image]

Then I pass that to the PythonCaller and expose those attributes.  The code looks like this:

```
import fmeobjects
import csv

# Template Function interface:
def getBounds(feature):
    global XMIN
    global XMAX
    global YMIN
    global YMAX


    outputDirectory = FME_MacroValues['Output_Directory']
    csvPath = outputDirectory + '\\Buffer Bounds.csv'
    coordlist = []

    with open(csvPath, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        bounds = reader.next()

    XMIN = float(bounds[0])
    XMAX = float(bounds[1])
    YMIN = float(bounds[2])
    YMAX = float(bounds[3])    

    feature.setAttribute("_xmin", XMIN)
    feature.setAttribute("_ymin", YMIN)
    feature.setAttribute("_xmax", XMAX)
    feature.setAttribute("_ymax", YMAX)


    print XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX
    pass

# Template Class Interface:
class FeatureProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def input(self,feature):
        self.pyoutput(feature)
    def close(self):
        pass
```

And the dialog box looks like this:

[image]

I can then pass those attributes as parameters to other WorkspaceRunners.

Now, my workspace runs in minutes instead of 2.5 hours.